# Python Decorator: Count Function Calls

Tags: python, function, variables, decorator

I want to create decorator that calculates funtion calls.
I am close but the problem is output is separate dictionary for every function, I want every function to be stored in one dictionary.
**How to make global dictionary which can store such data, I tried adding another decorator that created dictionary but it did not help, nonlocal variable also did not help either?**

```
def count(func):
    def inner():
        inner.calls += 1
        if inner.calls > 1:
            count_update = inner.dict[func.__name__] + 1
            update = {func.__name__:count_update}
            inner.dict.update(update)         
        else:     
            inner.dict={func.__name__:1}
        func()
        print(f'Current state {inner.dict}')           
    inner.calls = 0
    inner.dict={}
    return inner

@count
def show_date():
    current_time = datetime.now()
    current_time_formatted = current_time.strftime("%Y-%d-%B-%A")
    print(current_time_formatted)   
    return current_time_formatted

@count
def print_random_number2():
    numb = random.randint(0,10000)
    string_final=f'Number is {numb}'
    print(string_final)
    return string_final

show_date()
show_date()
show_date()
print_random_number2()
print_random_number2()
show_date()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a global dictionary by just creating a dictionary in the global scope (i.e. outside the function):

```
func_counts = {}
def count(func):
    def inner():
        func_counts[func.__name__] = func_counts.get(func.__name__, 0) + 1
        func()
        print(f'Current state {func_counts}')
    return inner
```

It's not necessary to declare it with `global` or `nonlocal` because you aren't rebinding it inside the function.

Comment: It worked huge thanks :) !
It was only one line, I feel like being retarded, because I tried something similar, but maybe was just too exhausted for this.